# SimpleXMLElement foreach child Array/Value

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I have the following code which works but seems like the incorrect way to implement this. Disregard the "...." that is all extra stuff we need not be concerned by. The issue I was having was that `Sup` was an array some of the time and other times it was just a value (or so `print_r` claimed, I thought/hoped it would have just been a one element array).

`$users` is a simpleXMLElement.

```
foreach($users as $user) {
    if ($user->InstSup->Sup[1] == '') {
        foreach($user->InstSup as $affid) {
        ....
    } else {
        foreach($user->InstSup->Sup as $affid) {
```

Here are the varying instances...

```
<Users>
    <User>
        <InstSup><Sup>1</Sup></InstSup>
    </User>
    <User>
        <InstSup><Sup>2</Sup><Sup>3</Sup><Sup>4</Sup><Sup>5</Sup></InstSup>
    </User>
</Users>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't trust the output of `print_r` (or `var_dump`) when you deal with **SimpleXMLElement**s. It's not showing the whole picture, better take a look at the XML as-is, for example with the [`asXML()` method](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.asxml).

Now to the problem you've got. When you want to have just the list (so to speak an "array") of the `<Sup>` elements that are children of `<InstSup>`, you better query the document with *Xpath*. It's fairly straight forward and gives you the array you want:

```
$users = new SimpleXMLElement($buffer);
$sups  = $users->xpath('/Users/User/InstSup/Sup');
foreach ($sups as $index => $sup) {
    printf("#%d: %s (%s)\n", $index, $sup, $sup->asXML());
}
```

This creates the following output:

```
#0: 1 (<Sup>1</Sup>)
#1: 2 (<Sup>2</Sup>)
#2: 3 (<Sup>3</Sup>)
#3: 4 (<Sup>4</Sup>)
#4: 5 (<Sup>5</Sup>)
```

And this is the `$buffer` to complete the example:

```
$buffer = <<<XML
<Users>
    <User>
        <InstSup><Sup>1</Sup></InstSup>
    </User>
    <User>
        <InstSup><Sup>2</Sup><Sup>3</Sup><Sup>4</Sup><Sup>5</Sup></InstSup>
    </User>
</Users>
XML;
```

As the line-up in the output shows, even though the `<Sup>` elements are inside (same-named but) different parent elements, the *XPath query expression*

```
/Users/User/InstSup/Sup
```

returns all the elements in that path from the document.

So hopefully you now better understand that it's not only that `print_r` is not that useful because it doesn't show the whole picture, but also by understanding how the document has it's nodes ordered, you can even more easily query the data with an Xpath expression.

Comment: I might have over simplified my example. Is the xpath absolute? I have some other things in the User element like firstname, lastname, userid, and optionally email. I tried this solution higher up and can't get it to process. `/Users/User/*`, `/Users/User/`, and `/Users/User` all fail for me. `Fatal error: Call to a member function asXML() on a non-object` which I think is from bad bath. Then `SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): Invalid expression` when I put in the asterisk.

Comment: @user3783243: Hmm, you must have some different XML acutally, because this works flawlessly, please see the online demo: https://eval.in/private/ab7393f6e89429 (feel free to edit to provoke the error you get and post link back here)

Comment: Well guess I was running into a case of the Fridays. This works fine now. Thanks.

Comment: Yes friday is one of the seven days in the week where such things tend to happen :)